# Ajax JavaScript Post Authentication Failed

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

Eu tenho uma LP que submete um formulário. Estou fazendo um teste para chamar um POST quando clicar no Botao enviar um JSON para minha API.
O JSON é convertido.
Mas quando chama o post do $.ajax dá ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o javascript utilizado:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var obj = { 
    title: "XXXXXX", 
    stage:{label:"XXXXX"},
    owner:{username:"email@email.com"},
    source:{name:"XXXX"},
    contact:{name:"nameXX", email:"mail@gmail.com", cellphone:"11999999999"},
    openingDate:"2020-03-11T15:30:00.949Z"
};

var dataJson = JSON.stringify(obj);
document.getElementById('btnSubmit').onclick = function(){
    console.log(dataJson);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myurl/rest/endpoint/register',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType : "json",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkZXNlbnZvbHZpbWVudG9AZ3J1cG9lbWlkaWEuY29tIiwiY29tcGFueSI6eyJpZCI6IjVkN2JhNzllNzIxYWQ2MDAwMWZiOGZmNiJ9LCJyb2xJkkI45I6IkFETUlOX1JPTEUiLCJleHAiOjE1ODM5NTM3Nzl9.GafZ7HDOK0Mv_Zu87eKU8St9K8_JfDdyZ2of3ciAguHlTKFGEy2fCkEr3g9PnAxaBADqw2rDqlJSydCuOyIvFg',
        },
        data: dataJson,
        success: function(data){
          console.log('succes: '+data);
        }
    });     
}
```

Comment: Será que não é porque vc está enviando o JSON em forma de string? Tente enviando em forma de objeto fazendo o parse: `var dataJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));`

Comment: A requisição nem chega a bater lá no método.....

Answer (score 0):

Você pode chamar uma função chamada `beforeSend` (Antes de enviar) no método AJAX e
definir o header nesta função. Em requisições com o ajax do jquery, também é aconselhável definir a propriedade `contentType` na requisição.

Veja abaixo o exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://myurl/rest/endpoint/register',
  method: 'POST',
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer OSEUTOKENAQUI');
  },
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkZXNlbnZvbHZpbWVudG9AZ3J1cG9lbWlkaWEuY29tIiwiY29tcGFueSI6eyJpZCI6IjVkN2JhNzllNzIxYWQ2MDAwMWZiOGZmNiJ9LCJyb2xJkkI45I6IkFETUlOX1JPTEUiLCJleHAiOjE1ODM5NTM3Nzl9.GafZ7HDOK0Mv_Zu87eKU8St9K8_JfDdyZ2of3ciAguHlTKFGEy2fCkEr3g9PnAxaBADqw2rDqlJSydCuOyIvFg',
  },
  data: dataJson,
  success: function (data) {
    console.log('succes: ' + data);
  }
});
```